# How to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!} = 2^{n} - 1 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I ran across that problem trying to count how many intersections of sets could be if none of them is a subset another.

If I have a set of sets X={A,B,C}, I have 4 combinations of intersections: $A \cap B, A \cap C, B \cap C, A \cap B \cap C, .. $  I also add $\overline{A}, \overline{B}, \overline{C},$ that means $\overline{A} = A - (B+C)$ I needed it for my own task. Having used combinatorics I have founded the series $C^n_1 + C^n_2 + C^n_3 + ... + C^n_n$. Here I didn't distinguish $A$ and $\overline{A}$. So I got the solution:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!} $$

Then I noticed that I didn't need combinatorics at all because I have binary code without zero:

```
C B A
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

So the number of combinations is $2^{n} - 1$. But now I can't figure out how to get the second solution from the first one using some consequence of mathematical operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$$

For $x=1$ and $y=1$ we have

$$(1+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}1^k1^{n-k}$$

whence we obtain

$$2^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}$$

Since $\binom{n}{0}=1$ we arrive at the desired result

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n-1$$

Answer (score 2):

We can write $$\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{i=0}\binom{n}{i} = \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+.........+\binom{n}{m}$$

$\bf{Combinational\; Proof::}$ Considering a group of $n$ person from which a subgroup of some

person is to be formed. This Subgroup may have $0$ person, $1$ person, $2$ person ans so on.

Thus the number of ways of forming Subgroup is $\displaystyle \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+.........+\binom{n}{m}$

Now all these are covered if we note that each person can be in $2$ ways, He is either in the group

or not in the group which will form $2^{n}$ Selections

Thus $$\displaystyle \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+.........+\binom{n}{m} = 2^{n}.$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+.........+\binom{n}{m} = 2^{n}-\binom{n}{0}=2^n-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the Binomial theorem.

$$\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} = \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} 1^i 1^{n-i} = 2^n$$
Now subtract the $i=0$ term.